# Deserialize array elements to list

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the following XML...

```
<configuration>
    <img name="name1" />
    <img name="name2" />
    <warn>
        <img name="warn1" />
    </warn>
</configuration>
```

...which I try to deserialize into...

```
[XmlType("img")]
public class ImageNameExceptionItemXml
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Filename;
}

[XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class ImageNameExceptionListXml: List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml>
{
    [XmlArray("warn")]
    [XmlArrayItem("img")]
    public ImageNameExceptionListXml WarnList { get; set; }
}
```

...but I end up with the WarnList property null.

I already tried...

```
[XmlElement("warn"}]
public ImageNameExceptionListXml WarnList { get; set; }
```

...or...

```
[XmlElement("warn"}]
public List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml> WarnList { get; set; }
```

...but I still end up with WarnList property null. Why is that?

Comment: The schema looks not good. Is it possible to change?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think the Serializer likes deserializing the extra properties on what it think is an array. So this may be tricky without explicitly implementing IXmlSerializable.

Comment: @findcaiyzh I can only change the `<warn>` node. Maybe I can try 

  <configuration>
    <img name="name1" />
    <img name="name2" />
    <warnImg name="warn1" />
  </configuration>

Comment: @sjlewis the problem is XmlSerializer just allow one type in array/list.<configuration><imgs><img... /><img ... /></imgs><warn ... /> is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go to the problem. The warn is a "root" element, so, you have to transform it in a class too:

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <img name="name1" />
  <img name="name2" />
  <warn>
      <img name="warn1" />
      <img name="warn2" />
  </warn>
</configuration>
```

The class:

```
[XmlType("img")]
public class ImageNameExceptionItemXml 
{ 
    [XmlAttribute("name")]     
    public string Filename; 
}

[XmlType("warn")]
public class WarnExceptionItemXml
{
    [XmlElement("img")]
    public List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml> ImgList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class ImageNameExceptionListXml
{
    [XmlElement("img")]
    public List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml> ImgList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("warn")]
    public WarnExceptionItemXml WarnList { get; set; } 
}
```

And the deserialize test:

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImageNameExceptionListXml));

ImageNameExceptionListXml teste = (ImageNameExceptionListXml)xml.Deserialize(new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open));
```

Comment: Do you have to repeat the same name both in `[XmlElement]` and `[XmlType]`?

Comment: @svick nope, you can use only in `[XmlElement]`, but is better to give the idea easier. And you using in a different class it's better to understand who class is connected to xml element.

Comment: To better understand the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer just allow one type in array/list. is fine. Post My test code:

```
[XmlType("img")]
[Serializable]
public class ImageNameExceptionItemXml
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Filename;
}

[XmlType("warn")]
[Serializable]
public class Warnning
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ImageNameExceptionItemXml))]
    public List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml> imgs { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("configuration")]
[Serializable]
public class ImageNameExceptionListXml
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Warnning))]
    public List<Warnning> warns{ get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ImageNameExceptionItemXml))]
    public List<ImageNameExceptionItemXml> imgs { get; set; }

}
```

xml:

```
<configuration>
<imgs>
    <img name="name1" />
    <img name="name2" />
</imgs>
<warns>
    <warn>
      <imgs>
        <img name="warn2" />
        <img name="warn1" />
      </imgs>
    </warn>
    <warn>
      <imgs>
        <img name="warn3" />
        <img name="warn4" />
      </imgs>
    </warn>
 </warns>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Vinicius Ottoni's answer is better.